# What is Unity InjectionConstructor Attribute?

Tags: c#, .net, unity-container

What is Unity InjectionConstructor Attribute and how it works ?

Comment: Agree. You're missing the accepted answer. Go for these 2 points! :)

Answer (score 31):

Basically this tells Unity to use the constructor that is specified with the attribute. Please [read this post](https://web.archive.org/web/20101121101709/http://codebetter.com/blogs/david.hayden/archive/2008/10/27/specifying-injection-constructor-using-unity-fluent-interface-for-loose-coupling-and-poco.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Please, add some of the content from that link here.

Answer (score 2):

This attribute is used to indicate which constructor to choose when the container attempts to build a type.

```
myclass {

 [InjectionConstructor]
 public myclass(interface1:XYZ, .....){}
}
```

It does something similar to the InjectionConstructor (not the attribute) in a more declarative way. But it lacks some features like using a named interface ex:

```
new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<IMyInterface>("implementation # 1"));
```